# How can I trigger my app to reopen whenever the device sits idle for a period of time?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that needs to reopen when the device isn't used, I've searched the internet but I didn't find what I was looking for.

How can I automatically reopen my app when the device isn't used for 10 seconds?

Comment: Interesting... But I doubt that it is possible

Comment: u need <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
and need to write a service that will be running in background and when time pass  as per your required limit then it will bring app to front

Comment: What you can do is here for `intent` is `user present` or make a `service` which note lock screen on and off note that time in storage make an alarm via alarm manger which wake the device and compare the noted value with current time if criteria meet open the app

Comment: You might want to elaborate on `isn't used`.  Will incoming calls and incoming messages (SMS or email) that the user doesn't respond too count as being used, or not.

Comment: @UsmanKurd Thats possible but how to check user presence?  at: DjHacktorReborn my phone is constantly awake using a wake_lock. at: psubsee2003 the phone will not use a sim card.

Comment: @UsmanKurd, READ_PHONE_STATE has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use WAKE-LOCK, which prevents the screen from going blank after a period of non-use.  Rather than "reopen" your app, simply prevent it from closing.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: Hi, I'm already using a wake lock to keep my phone awake. But when the user switches an app it doesn't reopen.

Answer (score 0):

The wake lock is no longer in effect once your user has switched out activities.

And if I installed an app that woke itself back up to the forefront after I'd switched out and away from it I'd uninstall.   What is it that you're trying to do that is so  important you've got to pester your user even after they've left your app?  Describe the scenario - maybe there's an alternative to annoying your user to death.